# Graphic cards compatibility

Tags: graphics, 10.04, hardware, compatibility

I am currently using an old desktop. it's a Dell Dimension 2400, Pentium 4, Intel Celeron 2.4 GHZ Processor. I need to upgrade the graphic card because when I installed Ubuntu 10.04 (32-bit), I was limited of it's use.

Every time I go and change the screensaver, it crashes and the monitor turns on and off contiously. I wanted to use the Advanced Desktop Settings so I can have enhanced effects while moving windows around but it won't let me.

There are many choices of graphic cards out there, however, I am only limited to a "PCI" only(not PCI-x or PCI-e) and only a "DDR"(not DDR2 or 3). My concern is what is the right graphic card for my desktop?...and that is also compatible with Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: PCI? not even AGP?

Comment: And regardless of the Motherboard supported RAM type, the card's VRAM is going to be GDDR3 or 2. For the last PCI or AGP released cards.

Answer (score 1):

This  is the newest i could find:

[image]

The Zotac GeForce GT 520 has one feature you don’t see on 99% of the graphics cards released today: ***`a PCI connector`***. Your typical motherboard still has a PCI slot or two, but for graphics cards the PCIe slot is the connection of choice offering much better performance.

The Zotac card uses the Nvidia GT 520 GPU and is clocked at 850MHz. The shader clock is running at 1620MHz with 48 shaders available to take advantage of. There’s 512MB of DDR3 memory running at 1333MHz, and your get VGA, DVI, and HMDI connections. The card also drags your system compatibility bang up to date with DirectX 11 and OpenGL 4.1 support.

---

I'm pretty sure the newest nvidia drivers or the nouveau drivers support the card.

[Source.](http://www.geek.com/articles/chips/zotac-launches-pci-directx-11-graphics-card-for-legacy-systems-20110929/)